# Comparing type of Generic associated type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, collections, protocols

I have the next code:

```
protocol Flyable {
  var airspeedVelocity: Double { get }
}

func topSpeed<T: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element == Flyable>(collection: T) -> Double {
  return collection.map { $0.airspeedVelocity }.reduce(0) { max($0, $1) }
}
```

I understood, by reading the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID192) that:

> You write a where clause by placing the where keyword immediately after the list of type parameters, followed by constraints for associated types or equality relationships between types and associated types.

This is the example given on the docs:

```
func allItemsMatch<C1: Container, C2: Container where 
C1.ItemType == C2.ItemType, C1.ItemType: Equatable> 
(someContainer: C1, _ anotherContainer: C2) -> Bool {
    // code
}
```

Note that when expressing that the associated type `ItemType` of the `C1` type must conform to `Equatable` protocol you use `:` and not `==`, why is that not the case in my example, where I have to use `==` to state that the `Element` associated type of `T.Generator` must conform with `Flyable`?

When changing `==` with `:` the compiler complains with this:

> error: cannot invoke 'topSpeed' with an argument list of type '([Flyable])' note: expected an argument list of type '(T)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/conformance-requirement). The where clause has the next grammar:

```
conformance-requirement → type-identifier­:­type-identifier­
same-type-requirement → type-identifier­==­type­
```

So, when you want to state that your type parameter conforms to certain protocol you use `:`. BUT, when you want your type to be exactly of a certain type, you use `==`. In my example, I wanted to take as a parameter a collection of `Flyable`. So, when trying to use `:` the compiler complained because `Flyable` doesn't conform to `Flyable`. `Flyable` IS `Flyable`, thus I must use `==` (or do something like what @Rahul Katariya answered)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using Generics.

```
protocol Flyable {
    var airspeedVelocity: Double { get }
}

func topSpeed(collection: [Flyable]) -> Double {
    return collection.map { $0.airspeedVelocity }.reduce(0) { max($0, $1) }
}

class Airplane: Flyable {

    var airspeedVelocity: Double = 10

}

class Rocket: Flyable {

    var airspeedVelocity: Double = 50

}

topSpeed([Airplane(),Rocket()]) //50
```

Comment: you should use maxElement() method instead of reduce `return collection.map{$0.airspeedVelocity}.maxElement() ?? 0`

Comment: Thanks. I'm still wondering why I have to use == and not : in my example though

Comment: or `return collection.maxElement({$0.0.airspeedVelocity<$0.1.airspeedVelocity})?.airspeedVelocity ?? 0`